# Fading menus without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm attempting a fading menu system of my own design without the assistance of jQuery. My problem of course is that I can get a menu to fade in or to fade out in a perfect world where the pointer doesn't quickly enter and leave the element that produces the menu (in my case a UL). But naturally I get a flickering effect when the cursor enters and exits the UL quickly. I imagine the need is for a great over-arcing event handler of my own design. I will post my code though I don't think that it will be needed as I'm probably going to scrap it and start over. Does anyone have links/ideas/or a good direction to start in with this?

JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = InitPage;

function InitPage(){

function fadeEffect(child, opacity, direction, e){
    if(direction && opacity != 1){
        opacity = opacity < 1?Math.round((opacity + 0.05)*100)/100:1;
        child.style.opacity = opacity;
        setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect(child, opacity, direction,e)},50);
    }else if(!direction && opacity != 0){
        opacity = opacity > 0?Math.round((opacity - 0.05)*100)/100:0;
        child.style.opacity = opacity;
        child.style.display = opacity == 0?"none":"block";
        setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect(child, opacity, direction,e)},50);
    }
}

function hoverMenu(e, oTarget){
    var isChildOf = function(pNode, cNode){
        if(pNode === cNode){
            return true;
        }
        
        while (cNode && cNode !== pNode){
            cNode = cNode.parentNode;
        }
        
        return cNode === pNode;
    }
    
    var hasChildMenu = function(pNode, cNode){
        while(cNode && cNode !== pNode){
            if(cNode.className == "ul_menu" || cNode.className == "li_menu"){
                cNode.style.display = "block";
                //cNode.style.opacity = 1;
                fadeEffect(cNode,0,true,e);
                //cNode.timer = setInterval(function(arg1,arg2,arg3){return function(){fadeEffect(arg1,arg2,arg3)}}(cNode,opacity,true),50);
            }
            cNode = cNode.previousSibling;
        }
        if(e.type == "mouseout"){
            e.cancelBubble();
        }
    }
    
    var target = e.target;
    
    if(!oTarget){
        oTarget = target;
    }
    
    var relTarg = e.fromElement;
    
    if(isChildOf(oTarget, relTarg) == false){
        //alert("mouse enters");
        hasChildMenu(oTarget, oTarget.lastChild);
    }
}

function unhoverMenu(e, oTarget){

    var isChildOf = function(pNode, cNode){
        //check to see if element is a child
        if(pNode === cNode){
            return true;
        }
        
        while (cNode && cNode !== pNode){
            cNode = cNode.parentNode;
        }
        
        return cNode === pNode;
    }
    
    var hasChildMenu = function(pNode, cNode){
        while(cNode && cNode !== pNode){
            if(cNode.className == "ul_menu" || cNode.className == "li_menu"){
                //cNode.style.opacity = 0;
                //cNode.style.display = "none";
                fadeEffect(cNode,1,false,e);
            }
            cNode = cNode.previousSibling;
        }
        if(e.type == "mouseover"){
            e.cancelBubble();
        }
    }
    
    var target = e.target;
    
    if(!oTarget){
        oTarget = target;
    }
    
    var relTarg = e.toElement;
    
    if(isChildOf(oTarget, relTarg) == false){
        hasChildMenu(oTarget, oTarget.lastChild);
    }
    
    function MenuEventHandler (e, oTarget){
    }
}

var ul_menu = document.getElementById("ul_grabbed");
ul_menu.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e1){return function(e){hoverMenu(e, e1)}}(ul_menu),false);
ul_menu.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e1){return function(e){unhoverMenu(e, e1)}}(ul_menu),false);
//document.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverMenu,false);
//document.addEventListener("mouseout",unhoverMenu,false);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bubble.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bubble_style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="menu_section">
            <ul id="ul_grabbed" class="ul_menu">Menu 1
                <li class="li_menu">item 1</li>
                <li class="li_menu">item 2</li>
                <li class="li_menu">item 3</li>
                <li class="li_menu">item 4</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="ul_menu">
                Menu 2
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0}
body{margin:0; padding:0;background-color:black}

div#background{
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
display:block;
width:800px;
height:100%;
vertical-align:middle;
background-color: green;}

div#menu_section{
margin:auto;
width:800px;
height:40px;
background-color:purple;}

div#monkey{
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:red;}

ul.ul_menu{
list-style:none;
display:block;
height:40px;
width:400px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
color:white;
}

li.li_menu{
height:20px;
display:none;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
color:white;
background-color:black;
opacity:0;}
```

Comment: For an example like this, you should create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) we can look at.

Comment: Step one is to look at jQuery—you'll be thoroughly confused by it's internal convolutions and learn never do that again. Step 2 is to go back to first principles and ask in a forum where you'll get good technical advice (comp.lang.javascript is good for that). Step 3 is to keep at it. You could do worse than look at [MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to this (junk code that it might be).  The below code demonstrates what I was trying to learn and perhaps can help others view the same thing.

HTML/CSS

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test_menu.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #menu_header{
            background-color:#617A2A;
            color:#C5DE8E;
            height:40px;
            width:120px;
            text-align:center;
            display:block;}

        #menu{
            opacity:0;
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            background-color:#AEC971;
            width:120px;}           

        #menu div{
            text-align:center;}

        #menu a, #menu a:link, #menu a:visited{
            color:#FFF;
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;}

        #menu a:hover{
            background-color:#414A2C;}

        #info_area{
            border: 1px black solid;
            position:float-left;
            margin-top:20px;
            width:512px;
            height:512px;
            overflow:auto;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu_header">
        Something
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></div>
        <div><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="info_area">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = InitPage;

function InitPage(){

var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
var menu_header = document.getElementById("menu_header");
var opacity_global = menu.style.opacity == ""?0:menu.style.opacity;
var timer = 0;

function fadeEffect(opacity, direction){
    if(direction && opacity != 1){
        opacity_global = opacity < 1?Math.round((opacity + 0.05)*100)/100:1;
        menu.style.opacity = opacity_global;
        if(opacity_global == 1){
            window.clearInterval(timer);
        }
        //setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect(child, opacity, direction);},50);
    }else if(!direction && opacity != 0){
        opacity_global = opacity > 0?Math.round((opacity - 0.05)*100)/100:0;
        menu.style.opacity = opacity_global;
        menu.style.display = opacity_global == 0?"none":"block";
        if(opacity_global == 0){
            window.clearInterval(timer);
        }
        //setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect(child, opacity, direction);},50);
    }
}

function eventHandler(e, menu, menu_header){
    var target = e.target;
    var menu_headerTarget = menu_header;
    var menuTarget = menu;
    var fromTarget = e.fromElement;
    var toTarget = e.toElement;
    var info = document.getElementById("info_area");

    var isChild = function(pNode, cNode){
        while(cNode && pNode !== cNode){
            cNode = cNode.parentNode;
        }
        return pNode === cNode;
    }

    //alert("e.type: " + e.type + "\ntarget: " + target + "\ntoElement: " + toTarget + "\nfromElement: " + fromTarget );

    if((isChild(target, fromTarget) == false) && (e.type == "mouseover") && (isChild(menuTarget,target)==false) && (isChild(menuTarget, fromTarget)==false)){
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        info.innerHTML += "<br />mouseover!";
        menuTarget.style.display = "block";
        timer = window.setInterval(function(){return fadeEffect(opacity_global, true);},25);
        //menuTarget.timer = setInterval(function(arg){arg.style.opacity += 0.05}(menuTarget),50);
    }else if((fromTarget === menu_headerTarget) && (isChild(menuTarget,toTarget) == false) && e.type == "mouseout"){
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        info.innerHTML += "<br />mouseout 1";
        //menuTarget.style.display = "none";
        timer = window.setInterval(function(){return fadeEffect(opacity_global, false);},25);
        //setTimeout(function(menuTarget){return function(){menuTarget.style.display = "none"}}(menuTarget),1000);
    }
    else if((isChild(menuTarget, target) == true) && (isChild(menuTarget, toTarget) == false) && (toTarget !== menu_headerTarget) && e.type == "mouseout"){
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        info.innerHTML += "<br />mouseout 2";
        //menuTarget.style.display = "none";
        //setTimeout(function(menuTarget){return function(){menuTarget.style.display = "none"}}(menuTarget),1000);
        timer = window.setInterval(function(){fadeEffect(opacity_global, false);},25);
    }else{
        info.innerHTML += "<br />Stopped an event!! " + "type: " + e.type + " target: " + target;
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}

menu_header.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){eventHandler(e, menu, menu_header);},false);
menu_header.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){eventHandler(e, menu, menu_header);},false);
menu.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){eventHandler(e, menu, menu_header);},false);
menu.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){eventHandler(e, menu, menu_header);},false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In an actual project, doing this without jQuery (or some other library) would make me wonder if you're a glutton for punishment.  Cross-browser animation is a relatively hard problem that's already been solved.

However, since this is a learning experience, here are a few pointers:

- One place to start would be to [examine how jQuery does animations](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js).
- You could cheat a little and use [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations).

Comment: Glutton or just wants to learn how it might work. We're masochists in at least some little way here, hurtling ourselves at these "machines" with our inscrutable ideas about what's right or not.

Comment: That's fair, @JaredFarrish.  If this is a learning exercise, a good place to start might be [examining how jQuery does its animations](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js).

Comment: This is a learning experiment honestly. I take it everyone has dodged such a problem :)

Comment: @RobG, that's not really fair -- the original question never mentioned that this is just for a learning experience.  (I'd never discourage learning!)  The discouragement was from doing this in an actual project.  Answer updated.

Comment: My apologies. I'm not at all discouraged :D